# Correctly receive from winapi socket

Tags: c++, sockets, winapi, recv

MSDN provides following code:

```
    int iResult;
    // Receive until the peer closes the connection 
    do { 

        iResult = recv(ConnectSocket, recvbuf, recvbuflen, 0); 
        if ( iResult > 0 ) 
            printf("Bytes received: %d\n", iResult); 
        else if ( iResult == 0 ) 
            printf("Connection closed\n"); 
        else 
            printf("recv failed: %d\n", WSAGetLastError()); 

    } while( iResult > 0 );
```

iResult store the number of bytes received! In my case I can't do it like this because the receive hangs if nothing was received (or end was reached) -> so the exit condition never match!

Something wrong and/or why the recv hangs here?

Greets

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because sockets are, by default, blocking. This means that calls to e.g. `recv` will block until something is received. You can use the [`ioctlsocket`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms738573%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function to make the socket non-blocking.

You do have to be prepared that `recv` can return with an [`WSAEWOULDBLOCK`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740668%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#WSAEWOULDBLOCK) error if nothing is available to be received. Or use polling functions such as [`select`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740141%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to know when you have data that can be received. If you don't want to poll, search for "asynchronous sockets" on MSDN to find both server and client examples.

Comment: You can also use `setsockopt()` to specify a timeout for blocking operations, without making the socket itself non-blocking.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, if there no incoming data is available at the socket, the recv blocks till data arrive. You can use [select()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740141%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to determine when more data arrives and then use recv() to read it.

Answer (score 0):

> the receive hangs if nothing was received

Correct.

> (or end was reached)

Incorrect. It returns zero under that circumstance. However 'end is reached' means that the peer has closed the connection. Possibly you have some other definition in mind?

I suspect your problem is that the peer isn't closing the connection and you are still expecting a zero. It doesn't work that way.